# simple pivot table of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I'm trying to do a seemingly very simple task.
Given a dataframe:

> daf = pd.DataFrame({'co':['g','r','b','r','g','r','b','g'], 'sh':['c','s','r','r','r','s','c','r']})
>
> ```
>     co  sh
> 0   g   c 
> 1   r   s 
> 2   b   r 
> 3   r   r 
> 4   g   r 
> 5   r   s
> 6   b   c
> 7   g   r
> ```

I'd like to count the number of records with the unique combination of 'co' and 'sh' values and output as a table with rows ['g','r','b'] and columns ['c','s','r']

> ```
>     c   s   r
> g   1   0   2
> r   0   1   1
> b   1   0   1
> ```

Can it be done using pivot_table?

Thank you,

Answer (score 10):

It can be done more simply using `pandas.crosstab`:

```
>>> pandas.crosstab(d.co, d.sh)
sh  c  r  s
co         
b   1  1  0
g   1  2  0
r   0  1  2
```

You can do it with `pivot_table`, but it will give you NaN instead of 0 for missing combos.  You need to specify `len` as the aggregating function:

```
>>> d.pivot_table(index='co', columns='sh', aggfunc=len)
sh   c  r   s
co           
b    1  1 NaN
g    1  2 NaN
r  NaN  1   2
```