# How to do partial dataframe transposition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, transpose

I have a dataframe like this:

```
+---------+--------------+-------+-------------+
| Customer|    invoice   | Amount| invoice type|
+---------+--------------+-------+-------------+
| Frank   |  invoice 1 n°|   150 |    type1    |
| Frank   |  invoice 2 n°|   300 |    type2    |
| Peter   |  invoice 1 n°|   450 |    type2    |
+---------+--------------+-------+-------------+
```

In which each line corresponds to an invoice

And I need to transform it into this:

```
+---------+-------------+--------+--------------+------------+--------+--------------+
| Customer|  invoice1   | Amount1| invoice1 type|  invoice2  | Amount2| invoice2 type|
+---------+-------------+--------+--------------+------------+--------+--------------+
| Frank   |  invoice1 n°|   150  |    type1     | invoice2 n°|  300   |     type2    |
| Peter   |  invoice1 n°|   450  |    type2     |            |        |              |
+---------+-------------+--------+--------------+------------+--------+--------------+
```

In which each line corresponds to a customer and the different invoices information are transposed to columns. If a client has more invoices than there are columns, new columns need to be created to include all the invoice information.

I see how to do a simple transposition in pandas, but I have absolutely no idea how I could do this easily.

Any help would be very appreciated

Comment: try this, [`simple pivot table of pandas dataframe
`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27738398/simple-pivot-table-of-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: I'm not quite sure as a pivot would create a new column for each unique value in the invoice column of the initial dataframe, am I wrong ? Here it would mean having a new column for each invoice as invoice numbers are unique, which is basically a transposition. 
Here the amount of new columns created depend on the maximum amount of unique invoices in my clients.

Answer (score 1):

To find the number of columns to expand horizontally, we find the cumulative value in ID. The number of columns is transformed with the `pivot_table()`. Then, it updates the table with the new column name.

```
df['flg'] = 1
df['flg'] = df.groupby('Customer')['flg'].transform(pd.Series.cumsum)
df2 = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['Customer'], values=['invoice','Amountinvoice','type'], columns=['flg'], fill_value='', aggfunc=lambda x: x)
new_cols = ['{}_{}'.format(x,y) for x,y in df2.columns]
df2.columns = new_cols
df2.reset_index(inplace=True)
df2 = df2.loc[:,['Customer','invoice_1','Amountinvoice_1','type_1','invoice_2','Amountinvoice_2','type_2']]

df2
|    | Customer   | invoice_1    |   Amountinvoice_1 | type_1   | invoice_2    | Amountinvoice_2   | type_2   |
|---:|:-----------|:-------------|------------------:|:---------|:-------------|:------------------|:---------|
|  0 | Frank      | invoice 1 n° |               150 | type1    | invoice 2 n° | 300.0             | type2    |
|  1 | Peter      | invoice 1 n° |               450 | type2    |              |                   |          |
```

Comment: Wow thanks a lot! It works perfectly !
Im not sure what the last line is for ? I feel like I have the same result before with the added value that i don't have to know in advance how many "invoices" instances at max i will need

Comment: The last line corresponds to a reordering of the expected output column. Glad to be of help.