# Dataframe without column names in matrix format using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a dataframe using python pandas without column names for 3 columns (user, week_date and count) as shown in the below picture from a csv file having 3 columns user, week_date and count.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V31ze.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5632.png)

Please try to let me know how can i transpose and get the similar output from csv?

Comment: Try this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/27738423/4985099

Comment: Thanks a lot Sushanth. I highly appreciate your quick response.

Comment: This question is Answered before check here[Answer to your header problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29287224/pandas-read-in-table-without-headers)