# Adding a header into python and changing a column into header and removing duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bloomberg

My dataframe is like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7i2R.png)

I wish to have it like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBpA1.png)

whats the best way to approach this problem? bear in mind the original dataframe is created when calling on a specific date range.

Comment: This is hardly a Bloomberg question. Better to tag with Python.

Comment: Don't share images of code/data. Copy/Paste the values as code into your answer.

Comment: you need to create pivot output.
below link may be of use:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27738398/simple-pivot-table-of-pandas-dataframe